# Why do I get hexadecimal values when I allocate a matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I would like to allocate a matrix in C using `malloc`. The compilation ends successfully but I get a strange value when I execute the program. Please here an example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
int rows=160, cols=160;
int *mat = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
int i, j;

for(i=0;i<160;i++) for(j=0;j<160;j++) mat[i * cols + j]=i+j;

for(i=0;i<160;i++) for(j=0;j<160;j++)
printf("R[%d][%d] = %p\n", i, j, (void*)mat[i * cols + j]);
}
```

I get after execution for example:

```
R[158][159] = 0x13d
```

Comment: `R[160][160]` is out-of-range. Indices are [0, size).

Comment: `<malloc.h>` is non-standard; the function `malloc()` (along with its friends) is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: 0x13d = 317 = 158 + 159

Comment: why do you use a variable for a constant like `rows` and `cols`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're accessing row 160 and column 160 of your matrix, but index ranges from 0 to 159 in your case.

Try resetting your `i` and `j` variables before trying to access your matrix.

**EDIT:**

if you want to see allocated value, you might want to do:

```
printf("R[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat[i * cols + j]);
```

Also, you should change your `malloc.h` include to `stdlib.h`, the latest being the standard one.

Comment: yes thank you! But when I print the full matrix I get a sort of hexadecimal values? But where may I put &?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik it's because you're using `%p` format specifier. If you want to see the values you wrote, you can remove your `void*` cast and change format specifier to `%d`.

Comment: That is @Mauren thank you for your powerful answer. Actually I would like to use the dynamic allocation in order to have a huge index! when I used the static one, I get segmentation error core dumped. Thank you so much for your help :) a

Answer (score 2):

In `C` array index starts from `0`. Hence your 2D array `R` ranges from `0` till `159` leading to a undefined behavior when you access element at `R[160][160]`

Format specifier `%p` is used in printf to print the address of memory locations. And values in those memory locations using `%d`.

Also you haven't `free()` the memory which you have allocated using `malloc()` making your program `leak` memory.